# Undefined name 'Lottie' - Error in flutter

Tags: flutter, android-animation, flutter-dependencies, lottie

How can i solve bellow mentioned errors in a simple flutter program

[image: Flutter_Lottie_Error]

Errors :

> Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:lottie/lottie.dart'.
> Try creating the file referenced by the URI, or Try using a URI for a file that does exist.

> Undefined name 'Lottie'.
> Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. did you run `flutter pub get`?

Comment: Hi,Yes i have tried many times.

Comment: run `flutter pub cache repair`

Comment: Did you try restarting your vscode?

Comment: Thanks, Now it's working!!,  "flutter pub cache repair" this command helped me.

Comment: Please include a [mcve] in your question; screenshots of code are not allowed by themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Check first your `pubspec.yaml` file if you have `lottie` under dependencies. If you do, press this button at top right corner if you are using `Visual Studio Code`
[image: screen]

Ohterwise type `flutter pub get` at your `cmd` to get the dependencies you are missing.

Comment: Installation is Perfectly fine, is require any other extra dependencies for lottie?